# Is `GRANT CREATE SESSION to "MYROLE"` working in Oracle 12 database?

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-12c

In a *Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production* I'm trying to assign the `CREATE SESSION` privilege to a custom role `MYROLE` and then assign `MYROLE` role to `MYUSER` user.

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION to "MYROLE"
GRANT "MYROLE" to "MYUSER"
```

When I try to connect I received:

> ORA-01045: user MYUSER lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied

What am I missing?

If I give `CREATE SESSION` grant directly to `MYUSER` it works.

EDIT:

I think that my issue was related to the fact that `MYUSER` hadn't a **DEFAULT ROLE**.

Comment: That should work. The (deprecated) `CONNECT` role does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be connected to wrong container database, probably CDB.

Here is a demo which is working fine for me.

I am connected to `orclpdb`, a pluggable database as `sysdba`.

```
[oracle@oracdb ~]$ sqlplus sys@orclpdb as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Sep 20 15:26:59 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create role myrole;

Role created.

SQL> grant create session to myrole;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create user testuser identified by testuser;

User created.

SQL> grant myrole to testuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn testuser/testuser@orclpdb
Connected.
SQL>
```

Comment: I've done your example in a clean PDB and worked as expected. I've to investigate why is not working on my other PDB...